# Geometric notion of differentiability of vector-valued vs. scalar-valued functions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

For a vector valued function $\mathbf{f}: X \subset  \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, the definition of differentiability suggests that if $\mathbf{f}$ is differentiable at point $\mathbf{a} \in X \subset \mathbb{R}^n $, then for $ \mathbf{x}$ near $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ can be approximated by the tangent hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^m$:
$$
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}) + D_{\mathbf{f}}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}) + \sum_i^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(x_i-a_i)
$$

This is the parametric equation of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^m$, the co-domain.

A special case of $\mathbf{f}$ is the scalar valued function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, with the equation of the tangent hyperplane:
$$
f(\mathbf{a}) + D_{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) = f(\mathbf{a}) + \nabla f(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})
$$
We see this as the point-normal form of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (domain and co-domain combined) , and it is tangent to the graph of $f$, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined by $\{(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1}) | x_{n+1}=f(x_1,...,x_n)\}$. This is quite different from the situation above of $\mathbf{f}$ (how do you define the graph of $\mathbf{f}$?), and I'm not sure what the special case of $m=1$ would mean (what does a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^1$ look like?).

How do I reconcile these two interpretations?

Comment: Graph of any function: $\{ (x,f(x)) \mid x\in \operatorname{dom} f\}$.

Comment: ok...my textbook only defined graph for a scalar-valued function. In that case can I generalize the second interpretation to the first by saying $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}) + D_{\mathbf{f}}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$ defines a $m$ dimensional "hyperplane" in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ with $n$ normal vectors (rows of $D_{\mathbf{f}}$) $\nabla \mathbf{f}_1$, $\nabla \mathbf{f}_2$, ..., $\nabla \mathbf{f}_n$

Comment: still I don't understand how the first (most general) interpretation works when $m=1$

Comment: It seems simple to just say that for $x$ near $a$, $f(x)$ can be approximated by a linear function: $f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)$.  (Technically, I should have said "affine" rather than linear.)  This statement makes sense for all values of $m$ and $n$.  The key idea of calculus is to study functions which, although they are not linear, are at least "locally linear" (or more accurately, "locally approximately linear").

Comment: @YiboYang it isn't a "hyper plane" unless $m=1$. In general it is called tangential space (in sense of affine (sub)space).

Comment: Why shouldn't the general interpretation apply to the case $m=1$? I am confused.

Comment: @user251257 I was fixated on the idea of a "tangent plane" ...So generally, I can see the affine approximation as either an $m$ dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, or an $n$ dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

Comment: Actually scratch the part about the dimensions of affine subspaces as the vectors in $D_\mathbf{f}$ may not be independent

Comment: @YiboYang the (affine) dimension of the tangential space depends on regularity conditions on the Jacobian.